# Using *Darwin as a test bed for Mac OSX applications

Tags: testing, macos, virtualization, darwin

Since Mac virtualization is technically illegal on anything but a Mac computer, is it possible to use one of the Darwin distros as a platform to test applications meant for Mac OSX?

From the little I've read, it seems *Darwin and MacOSX have a very tight relationship, but I haven't really found any information on the internet about using Darwin for MacOSX development -- So I'm a little skeptical if it is even possible.

Has anyone tried it?

Comment: What is your motivation here?  Do you want to save money on apple hardware?

Comment: Pretty much. I don't have the funds to invest in a Mac desktop computer. I might, in the future, but since I only need a test environment for open source development, the financial incentive is just not there.

Comment: Something being against the EULA is not the same as illegal.

Comment: @Coxy If a particular EULA was found by a court to constitute a binding contract, then any action which breached that EULA would indeed be illegal. I know that "if" is a fair-sized one, but your comment seems overstated at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Darwin does not have Aqua or any of the Core technologies, so only pure POSIX apps can be tested.